# use an array to get objects names?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, for-loop

I have multiple problems here so let me explain first.
I want to check whether the user has enough points for each item in the object, and then check whether the user has reached maximum level with that item, and write info in HTML accordingly. To simplify, heres how the code looks:

```
var player = { 
     points: 0, 
     lv: { item1: 1, item2: 3, ... , item9: 4 },
     maxLv: { item1: 10, item2: 15, ... , item9: 40 }
}
var names = [
     "item1", "item2", ... , "item9"
]
```

Now in the function which removes points and sets masteries is the function where I want to make this check, I thought of having a for loop, like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
     if(player.points < 0 || player.lv[names[i]] ...
```

Let me stop here. The `player.lv[names[i]]` doesn't work. But the console log of `[names[i]]` returns item1, item2, just fine, so `player.lv[names[3]]` should return `player.lv.item3`. For some reason, it doesn't.

```
for(i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
     if(player.points < 0 || player.lv[names[i]] < player.maxLv[names[i]]) {
          document.getElementById(names[i] + "click").innerHTML = "Not enough points";
     }
     else(player.Lv[names[i]] >= player.maxLv[names[i]]) {
          document.getElementById(names[i] + "click").innerHTML = "Maxed";
     }
}
```

Why isn't my method working? I've been beating my head over this for some time now...
Thanks!

Comment: And what if you try `player.lv[i]`? You get items from an array by their index number.

Comment: How do you define enough points in your requirement?

Comment: There is an object containing max levels. player.maxLv

Comment: Calaris but I need to get player.lv.name1, player.lv.name2, player.lv[i] would return player.lv.1, etc...

Comment: `else(player.Lv[names[i]] >= player.maxLv[names[i]])` should throw a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error right here:

```
else(player.lv[names[i]] >= player.maxLv[names[i]]) {
```

You can't have an `else` with a conditional, it should be `else if`:

```
else if (player.lv[names[i]] >= player.maxLv[names[i]]) {
```

Demo:

```js
var player = { 
     points: 0, 
     lv: { item1: 1, item2: 3, item3: 4 },
     maxLv: { item1: 10, item2: 15 , item3: 40 }
};
var names = [
     "item1", "item2" , "item3"
];

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     if(player.points < 0 || player.lv[names[i]] < player.maxLv[names[i]]) {
          document.getElementById(names[i] + "click").innerHTML = "Not enough points";
     }
     else if(player.lv[names[i]] >= player.maxLv[names[i]]) {
          document.getElementById(names[i] + "click").innerHTML = "Maxed";
     }
}
```

```html
<div id="item1click"></div>
<div id="item2click"></div>
<div id="item3click"></div>
```

Everything else in your code seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for this response. There was indeed an error with when I checked, so I made it to work by always setting to "Not enough points" or "Click to learn" whether user has / or hasn't any points, and then in a for loop I checked every to see if maxed to insert "Maxed" into HTML.

Comment: Also, player.lv[names[i]] needs to go like:
player.lv[names[i].toString()] - in order to return correct values.

Comment: @MiloSx7 nice! Glad to help!